# Why are fluorides of transition metals unstable in low oxidation states?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, transition-metals, oxidation-state

Why are fluorides of transition metals unstable in low oxidation states?

I would think that since fluorine and oxygen are highly electronegative, it's obvious that they be stable at high oxidation states. However, $\ce{Cl}$  is also highly electronegative, but it does exist in low oxidation states with transition metals.

For example $\ce{CuCl}$ exists  but not $\ce{CuF}$ and  $\ce{TiCl2}$ exists but not $\ce{TiF_{2}}$. Why is it so?

> *Fluorides of transition metals unstable in low oxidation states*

This is the statement given in my high school chemistry text book but no explanation provided. I am interested to know the reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the example of $\ce{CuF}$ which is not known.

Reason: $\ce F$ is such an electronegative element that it will always oxidise $ \ce{Cu}$ to $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and not $\ce{Cu^1+}$. Hence, whenever $\ce{Cu}$ reacts with flourine, copper(II) flouride is formed. The following reaction illustrates this:

$$\ce{Cu + F2 -> CuF2}$$

$\ce{CuF2}$ loses fluorine at temperatures above $\pu{950 °C}$.  $\ce{CuF}$ will be formed initially and as your question says, it is highly unstable so it will be transformed to some other stuff and the reactions are:

$$\ce{2CuF2  -> 2CuF (unstable) + F2}$$

$$\ce{2CuF  -> CuF2 + Cu}$$

Similarly, you can illustrate this for $\ce{VF2}$.

Comment: Your answer meanders around in a non-meaningful way. If anything, the final two reactions are relevant. For example, what happens if copper(I) ions and fluoride ions meet in solution? In the case of copper(II) and iodide, a redox reaction will take place due to the respective standard potentials forming copper(I) iodide and iodine. But fluoride ions won’t be reduced any more in solution.

Comment: Actually it could disproportionate, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(I)_fluoride.   CuF is better known in complexes where the copper is also bound to a softer base.